# Animation Nodes - convert letters to curve

Tags: animation-nodes

How can I convert each letter to separate curve object with the Animation Nodes?
I'm  using Decompose Text, not Split Text - (I need Whitespaces on). My AN is 2.2.2 with Blender 2.93.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

[image]

The object instancer is a "object factory" which creates (instances) objects. So here i take the text length to create as many instances/objects of my "original" beziercurve as letters in the word are.

Comment: Thanks, Chris, that's an interesting solution. As I can see, formatting will be copied from source text. One question - there's some Bezier Curve in the Object Instancer - whai is this for and how it was selected? I'm a noob AN, so some explaining would be welcome.

Comment: if my answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left of my answer. Thank you. I updated my answer.